# Change teaser image size

Tags: 8, media, nodes

I've noticed that the article images are sized to a width of 220px to be displayed in the teaser on the frontpage in Drupal 8. I'm wondering how to change that to 300px, for example.

I created an image style with the size I want with the image module at `admin/config/media/image-styles`, but how do I associate that with the teaser that's shown on the home page? I looked in the `Frontpage` view, but didn't see any way of editing the image style there.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in the view mode "teaser" of the content type "article":

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser
```

Go there and click on the setting symbol in the field "image" and choose the new image style.

Comment: Ah, there it is, thanks! I went to manage the display before, but I totally didn't see the "Teaser" tab there.